# Selenium:Chromedriver:Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-manager, selenium-java

I'm new to selenium and stuck on launching URL in chrome.

selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
here's code snip

```
import java.time.Duration;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class GoogleTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().clearDriverCache().setup();
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        
        driver.get("https://google.com");
    }
}
```

I'm seeing following error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Chrome browser is managed by my organization. I tried deleting policies from registry editor but it could not solve this issue. Policies keeps re appearing even after setting values to 0 . If anyone aware about this issue , please help.

Answer (score 1):

WebDriver uses ChromeDriver so you need to download it

https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/

I would also recommend doing all WebDriver work inside the NUnit framework